# Two different activities with SupportMapFragment shares the same fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

as in title i've in my project, which uses architecture components (version beta1 at time of write), two different activities, the first one is a search activity which contains a fragment for view results as list and a fragment that contains a SupportMapFragment for view results on map.

when i click a marker or a list item I open a new acitivity that shows the item details and the position on a map.

In the layout map fragments have different ids, for the search one is @+id/map_search and for detail is @+id/map_detail

when i start the detail activity i noticed that the map fragment that is shown is the fragment of the first activity.

Any idea to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Updated today architecture components to beta2 and everything went ok